# Java - XML Serialization: exists a library to specify own annotations?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, annotations

I'd like to transform my java code into 2 different xml files. One, which is kept internal, storing all objects, states, ... One, which stores on-demand some other parts of my code, but in another syntax as the first one.

I'd wonder if there exists a library where I can define my own annotations and create the xml independent from each others.

I know some libraries like simple, which provides a fixed set of annotations and crawl all of those. But this doesn't fit my need, since I want to crawl just a subset of the annotation for the relative xml file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways for you to write custom De/Serializers for Jackson [here](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/) is an example.

You can also create custom annotations. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation) is an example from Stackoverflow. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields) is another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I decided to combine Simple and XStream, which both works for Android.

Comment: Hopefully you found it useful.