# Custom annotation with Jackson 2 Java to JSON deserializer

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am working on a REST service using Jackson2 and Spring.

I know Jackson2 provides a set of very useful annotations. As per a requirement, we have to introduce our own custom annotations (like `@Summary`, `@Detail` etc).

I want to understand if it is possible to make Jackson use my own annotations along with its provided ones.

Appreciate if anyone can show some examples or point me to some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/ here is a good tutorial but I think you need to add @jsonserializer and @jsondeserealizer above the selected field, those annotations receive a class in which you should extend from serializer and deserializer in each case and implement the logic you want for the process.

http://texscribbles.blogspot.mx/2010/07/custom-json-serialization-with-spring.html?m=1

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
private Date approvalDate;



public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

@Override
public void serialize(final Date value, final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeString(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, How can I get access to annotations inside this `serialize()` method? Meaning, can I use reflection inside this method? Could you please provide some pointers?

Comment: Probably this link will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Contextual Handlers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureContextualHandlers) in the docs. This solution can be more elegant (depending on your use case) since you can register the serializer at the mapper and don't need to reference a custom serializer in your actual class.