# Substitute complicated combo of annotations with one custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

In my current project I have this group of big and complicated annotations I have to put on a lots of fields around my class. They are Jackson json annotations.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = IViewableToReferenceSerializer.class, contentUsing = IViewableToReferenceSerializer.class)
private ComplexeObject myObject;
```

and I would like to substitute it to something like:

```
@JsonAsReference 
private ComplexeObject myObject;
```

I already tested the system without the custom annotation and it works fine. I though I could define my annotation as (for example):

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonSerialize(using = IViewableToReferenceSerializer.class, contentUsing = IViewableToReferenceSerializer.class)
public @interface JsonAsReference {
}
```

So my question is: Is it even possible? Or am I just doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**: I found an answer for the particuliar Jackson case in this thread
[Create a custom Jackson annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation)

but I am open to any general case solution.

Comment: found the answer for Jackson json in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation ... but I'd be interested in a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the default jackson library you will have no luck.

Here a code snippet from `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` (from jackson 1.9.13)

```
public Object findSerializer(Annotated a) 
{
    /* 21-May-2009, tatu: Slight change; primary annotation is now
     *    @JsonSerialize; @JsonUseSerializer is deprecated
     */
    JsonSerialize ann = a.getAnnotation(JsonSerialize.class);
    if (ann != null) {
        Class<? extends JsonSerializer<?>> serClass = ann.using();
        if (serClass != JsonSerializer.None.class) {
            return serClass;
        }
    }

   ....
}
```

As you can see only the annotation `JsonSerialize` will be taken into account. Jackson will not search for a `JsonSerialize` annotation on other annotation like you wanted.

You can **implement an own AnnotationIntrospector** and provide it to the `SerializationConfig` and `DeserializationConfig`, e.g.

```
AnnotationIntrospector annIntr = ....; // your implementation

ClassIntrospector<? extends BeanDescription> intr = new BasicClassIntrospector();
VisibilityChecker<?> vc = VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance();
TypeFactory typeFactory= TypeFactory.defaultInstance();

SerializationConfig serConfig = new SerializationConfig(intr, annIntr, vc, null,
            null, typeFactory, null);
DeserializationConfig deserConfig = new DeserializationConfig(intr, annIntr, vc, null,
            null, typeFactory, null);

// null means use a default implementation
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(null, null, null, serConfig, deserConfig);
```

Comment: thanks Rene but like I said regarding the peculiar case of Jackson I already found a solution ... that is way more simple than yours.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation

Comment: Yes ok. So my answer is just a hint if you can not use another lib. :)